# wso2_carbon_db across different wso2 product, should it be same db?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

I have installed WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Business Process Server. Both product has wso2_carbon_db, so my question is whether both product should be configured with single db_instance of wso2_carbon_db ? or they should be configured with two different db_instance such as am_wso2_carbon_db and bps_wso2_carbon_db ?? please advice. I am using PostgresSql as db.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wso2_carbon_db should not be shared among different instances. It consists of instance local information. Sharing it among products might leads to issues. Therefore that should be local to the particular instance.

Comment: Thank you, but what if both wso2 products (wso2am, and wso2bps) running on same server ? in this case can we have shared wso2_carbon_db?

Comment: Still no. It is instance specific :)