# Sharing Carbon databases between APIM-IS-BROKER

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to deploy a solution with the following components :

- IS as Key Manager
- Api Manager
- Message Broker

I've seen that every wso2 product have a CARBON DB with informations about registry and user however it's not clear in the docs if the same CARBON DB instance can be shared among multiple wso2 products.
There is no clustering in my architecture, just 3 products on different servers. We are using one Postgres instance as the db and we cannot understand if we should create different CARBON DB (registry+users) or use the same for the above mentioned products. Thanks everyone
ps. i have found this reply but it's quite old, so I'm asking again
[wso2_carbon_db across different wso2 product, should it be same db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883933/wso2-carbon-db-across-different-wso2-product-should-it-be-same-db)

Comment: Could you please share any code you've produced?

Comment: @Christopher hi, I've not produced any code actually. My question is about the design of a new architecture from scratch with the three wso2 components mentioned above.My doubt is about sharing the CARBON DB among multiple distributer wso2 products. If my question wasn't clear just tell me, I'll try to be more precise. Thank you

Comment: If you want you can point to the same db for userdb. It is up to you. The users will be shared with all the products. like that the registrydb can be also shared. Here is one guide for apim-is deployment. https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Comment: @senthalan hi, thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me the difference between WSO2_CARBON_DB and WSO2REG_DB and WSO2UM_DB ? I cannot find the scripts to create the last 2 databases. There is no trace of creation of that databases in the documentation and it is not clear if they are both an alternative to the carbon database, since the carbon db itself contain a lot of tables with names that start with REG_ and UM_. Thank you